# Filter custom options in order items

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

Is there any way to filter custom options in Order items.

I have analysed that order items custom options are saved in `sales_flat_order_item` table under the column `product_options`.

My question is how to set `addtofilter` for custom options

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can filter it by any function. you will need to get selected custom options from order and need to check statically if your option is selected or not.

```
<?php
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('sales/order_item_renderer_default');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $block->setItem($item);
    $_options = $block->getItemOptions();
    foreach ($_options as $option) {
        $label = $option['label'];
        $textValue = $option['print_value'];
        if($label == 'labelvalue'){
            //do your stuff
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But actually I want to load it in order collection